# Running ant with phpunit crashes

Tags: laravel, ant, phpunit, lumen

I am trying to use ant and phpunit together but I am getting an error that the phpunit has crashed but the build is successful. This is a lumen framework

```
MacBook-Pro:test-api test$ ant phpunit
Buildfile: /Users/test/Code/test-api/build.xml

phpunit:
     [exec]
     [exec] Running phpunit in 4 processes with /Users/test/Code/test-api/vendor/bin/phpunit
     [exec]
     [exec] Configuration read from /Users/test/Code/test-api/phpunit.xml
     [exec]
     [exec]
     [exec]
     [exec]   [RuntimeException]
     [exec]   Coverage file /private/var/folders/jp/qjjd9lr50z74kbj_gwcc3bsr0000gn/T/CV_LaTe66 is empty. This means a PHPUnit process has crashed.
     [exec]
     [exec]
     [exec] paratest [-p|--processes PROCESSES] [-f|--functional] [--no-test-tokens] [-h|--help] [--coverage-clover COVERAGE-CLOVER] [--coverage-html COVERAGE-HTML] [--coverage-php COVERAGE-PHP] [-m|--max-batch-size MAX-BATCH-SIZE] [--filter FILTER] [--whitelist WHITELIST] [--phpunit PHPUNIT] [--runner RUNNER] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP] [-c|--configuration CONFIGURATION] [-g|--group GROUP] [--exclude-group EXCLUDE-GROUP] [--stop-on-failure] [--log-junit LOG-JUNIT] [--colors] [--testsuite [TESTSUITE]] [--path PATH] [--] [<path>]
     [exec]
     [exec] Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can do this without the `ant` and with `phpunit` alone.

we just need to run the `phpunit --coverage-text` or `phpunit --coverage-html <dir>`